# Return model to controller with list property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am passing a model to a view with a property that is a collection of, let's say, books. In my view I am using a foreach loop to create a table of the books in my collection, each with name, author, etc.

I want the user to be able to add/edit/delete books on client side. Then I want to be able to pass back to the controller the model, with the collection of books reflecting the changes made.

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean you don't want to save changes until the entire list is posted back? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I plan to use the values to save to database on postback, so i dont want to save values until they hit save in case they make a mistake and close out of the browser.

Or am i missing something?

Comment: Well, you provide them with the list, and they can edit/delete each item on the list. You don't have to post the whole collection back to the server, only the one that is modified.

Comment: hmm, that is a valid point, i dont need ot pass the whole list back. But what if they add 2 books edit a 3rd and remove one from the collection?

Comment: In that case, each of those actions would cause a post to save that particular book instance. I guess it really does depend on how much client side work you want.

Comment: solved it without the use of any jquery/knockout/ajax. Since i have under 10 rep points i need to wait 4 more hours to post answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it without the use of ajax/jquery/knockout:

Basically i needed to wrap the cshtml page in a @using (Html.BeginForm(~)){} tag, and then use a for loop (NOT a foreach) to display each of the items in the List. Then i needed to create a @Html.HiddenFor for each item in the list. When i submit the form i take the model as a parameter and the items populate the list. I cannot show my actual code, so i hastily relabeled some of the key variables so i hope you guys can make sense of it, but this is essentially how i got it to work

Here is the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult BookStore(int storeId)
{
    //model contains a list property like the following:
    //public List<Books> BooksList { get; set; }
    //pass the model to the view
    var model = new BookStoreModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

This is the view

```
@model BookStore.Models.BookStoreModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("BookStoreSummary", "BookStore", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
<fieldset>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LastModified)
//some html stuff here
<table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<thead>
  <tr class="ui-widget-header BookTable">
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookList.FirstOrDefault().Title)        </th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookList.FirstOrDefault().Author)</th>

   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.BookList.Count; i++)
{
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookList[i].Author)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BookList[i].Author)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookList[i].BookId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookList[i].Title)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BookList[i].Title)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>

</fieldset>
}
```

and the post back controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 //[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
 public ActionResult BookStoreSummary(BookStoreModel model)
 {
    //do stuff with model, return
    return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: I'm glad that this solved your issue, but I don't believe this actually works as you describe in your question.  This will not store a set of new books created on client to be saved with one server action.  I suppose it depends on your specific UI interaction, are you only allowing one new entry?

Comment: Actually i am able to add several books to the grid and send them all back to the controller as several new items in the list. As long as i make sure to increment the generated ID by 1 and include all of the info for that "item" in the list it adds it with no problem.

As far as i can tell it looks for that generated id for the list object and starts counting up. so an example ID is BookList_1__Author_Text. The list object is BookList, first object in list, property name and property type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

Say you have a form and you have collection named "Books". If you want to add new book programmatically , you could use jQuery and ajax. Fist you need some Helper classes.

Following classes help you create unique book item to add to collection of books in your view. As you know every field should have unique prefix, so model binder van distinguish between form elements

```
public static class HtmlClientSideValidationExtensions
{
        public static IDisposable BeginAjaxContentValidation(this HtmlHelper html, string formId)
        {
            MvcForm mvcForm = null;

            if (html.ViewContext.FormContext == null)
            {
                html.EnableClientValidation();
                mvcForm = new MvcForm(html.ViewContext);
                html.ViewContext.FormContext.FormId = formId;
            }

            return new AjaxContentValidation(html.ViewContext, mvcForm);
        }

        private class AjaxContentValidation : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly MvcForm _mvcForm;
            private readonly ViewContext _viewContext;

            public AjaxContentValidation(ViewContext viewContext, MvcForm mvcForm)
            {
                _viewContext = viewContext;
                _mvcForm = mvcForm;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (_mvcForm != null)
                {
                    _viewContext.OutputClientValidation();
                    _viewContext.FormContext = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class CollectionValidation
    {

        private const string idsToReuseKey = "__htmlPrefixScopeExtensions_IdsToReuse_";

        public static IDisposable BeginCollectionItem(this HtmlHelper html, string collectionName)
        {
            var idsToReuse = GetIdsToReuse(html.ViewContext.HttpContext, collectionName);
            string itemIndex = idsToReuse.Count > 0 ? idsToReuse.Dequeue() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            // autocomplete="off" is needed to work around a very annoying Chrome behaviour whereby it reuses old values after the user clicks "Back", which causes the xyz.index and xyz[...] values to get out of sync.
            html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}.index\" autocomplete=\"off\" value=\"{1}\" />", collectionName, html.Encode(itemIndex)));

            return BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(html, string.Format("{0}[{1}]", collectionName, itemIndex));
        }

        public static IDisposable BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(this HtmlHelper html, string htmlFieldPrefix)
        {
            return new HtmlFieldPrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix);
        }

        private static Queue<string> GetIdsToReuse(HttpContextBase httpContext, string collectionName)
        {
            // We need to use the same sequence of IDs following a server-side validation failure,  
            // otherwise the framework won't render the validation error messages next to each item.
            string key = idsToReuseKey + collectionName;
            var queue = (Queue<string>)httpContext.Items[key];
            if (queue == null)
            {
                httpContext.Items[key] = queue = new Queue<string>();
                var previouslyUsedIds = httpContext.Request[collectionName + ".index"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previouslyUsedIds))
                    foreach (string previouslyUsedId in previouslyUsedIds.Split(','))
                        queue.Enqueue(previouslyUsedId);
            }
            return queue;
        }

        private class HtmlFieldPrefixScope : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly TemplateInfo templateInfo;
            private readonly string previousHtmlFieldPrefix;

            public HtmlFieldPrefixScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string htmlFieldPrefix)
            {
                this.templateInfo = templateInfo;

                previousHtmlFieldPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
                templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = previousHtmlFieldPrefix;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then we assume you have a partial view for adding books like this :

```
@model Models.Book
 @using (Html.BeginAjaxContentValidation("form"))
    {
        using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Books"))
        {



        <div class="fieldcontanier">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="fieldcontanier">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
        </div>

       ...

        }
    }
```

and assume there is a "add new book" link in form which you have defined following event for that in jQuery :

```
 $('a ').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("NewBook")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (context) {
                        $('#books').append(context);


                        $("form").removeData("validator");
                        $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
                    }
                });
            });
```

In above code, first you request to action called NewBook, which returns a partial view I mentioned earlier, then it loaded after other books in page and then for unobtrusive validation to apply we use last tree lines.

Comment: So if this collection is a property of the model i pass to the view, will i be able to return the model back to the controller and reference this updated collection as a property of model?

Comment: Yes you could. Say you have list property called "Books" and defined like this : List<Book> Books...

Comment: i'll give that a try and mark correct if it works, thanks for the response by the way

Comment: solved it without the use of any jquery/knockout/ajax. Since i have under 10 rep points i need to wait 4 more hours to post answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely possible.  I'm currently using KnockOut on client and it will allow you to bind to a collection of a Javascript object, render each item as a template, add to, delete from, then post the entire collection back to server for processing.  You will need to handle things like state of deleted books, and hide them from the binding, but it's all doable.

Here's the KO syntax you would need in your view:

```
<table>
   <!-- ko foreach: {data: books } -->
   <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: title" />
   </tr>
   <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

This will create a table with 1 row for each item in books.. those objects require a 'title' property which will be the only value in the table.

Knockout is a great library and I've had a lot of fun learning and developing with it lately.  You can get more information on their project page here: http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: does this pass the collection back as a property in the model?

Comment: Yes, with KO the basic workflow would be, call server action, process returned data into a javascript ViewModel object (this is what contains your Books collection).  This ViewModel is then bound against the page.  Those ko comments and data-bind attributes instruct KO how to build the dom.  On save, you convert that viewmodel to JSON and post to server for saving.  That viewmodel contains all books. Info: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

Comment: solved it without the use of any jquery/knockout/ajax. Since i have under 10 rep points i need to wait 4 more hours to post answer